# SQL Query taking forever

Tags: sql-server, datetime, join

I have this webapplication tool which queries over data and shows it in a grid. Now a lot of people use it so it has to be quite performant.

The thing is, I needed to add a couple of extra fields through  joins and now it takes forever for the query to run.

If I in sql server run the following query:

```
select top 100 *
from bam_Prestatie_AllInstances p
join bam_Zending_AllRelationships r on p.ActivityID = r.ReferenceData
join bam_Zending_AllInstances z on r.ActivityID = z.ActivityID
where p.PrestatieZendingOntvangen >= '2010-01-26' and p.PrestatieZendingOntvangen < '2010-01-27'
```

This takes about 35-55seconds, which is waaay too long. Because this is only a small one.

If I remove one of the two date checks it only takes 1second. If I remove the two joins it also takes only 1 second.

When I use a queryplan on this I can see that 100% of the time is spend on the indexing of the PrestatieZendingOntvangen field. If I set this field to be indexed, nothing changes.

Anybody have an idea what to do?

Because my clients are starting to complain about time-outs etc.

Thanks

Comment: please post table schema

Comment: use operator between ... and ... for the two dates

Comment: why do you have the joins if you do not use them in `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Because I need data from the other databases and need to cast them to a List in c#. But apparently if I do where's on my z data it goes a lot faster, so there is some truth in what you are saying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides the obvious question of an index on the `bam_Prestatie_AllInstances.PrestatieZendingOntvangen` column, also check if you have indices for the foreign key columns:

- p.ActivityID (table: `bam_Prestatie_AllInstances`)
- r.ReferenceData (table: `bam_Zending_AllRelationships`)
- r.ActivityID (table: `bam_Zending_AllRelationships`)
- z.ActivityID (table: `bam_Zending_AllInstance`)

Indexing the foreign key fields can help speed up JOINs on those fields quite a bit!

Also, as has been mentioned already: try to limit your fields being selected by specifying a specific list of fields - rather than using `SELECT *` - especially if you join several tables, just the sheer number of columns you select (multiplied by the number of rows you select) can cause massive data transfer - and if you don't need all those columns, that's just wasted bandwidth!

Comment: I already did all this, it's standard. And I also select fields, it was just to make the query a little bit more readable.
The main issue I found out is that if I remove the top 100 it goes a LOT faster, I think it copies it to a temp db when i use top 100. I obviously can't use all of them because this would overload our network.

Answer (score 2):

1. Specify the fields you want to retrieve, rather than *
2. Specify either Inner Join or Outer Join

Answer (score 0):

Try between?

```
where p.PrestatieZendingOntvangen 
   between '2010-01-26 00:00:00' and '2010-01-27 23:00:00'
```

Comment: that's just syntactic sugar - the underlying query plan will be identical, so that really doesn't help, I'm afraid.

Comment: plus that would possibly return different results. BETWEEN is inclusive, plus you've stated 23:00....

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed an **indexes** on the date fields in your `Where` clause.

If not, I would create a INDEX on that fields to see if it makes any differences to yourv time.

Of course, Indexes will take up more disk space so you will have to consider the impact of that extra index.

EDIT:

The others have also made good points about specifing what columns you require in the `Select` instead of * (wildcard), and placing more indexes on foreign keys etc.

Comment: ahh ok... there i go jumping the gun before reading the question fully!

Answer (score 0):

Someone from DB background can clear my doubt on this.

I think, you should specify date in the style in which the DB will be able to understand it.
for e.g. Assuming, the date is stored in mm/dd/yyyy style inside the table & your query tries to put in a different style of date for comparison (yyyy-mm-dd), the performance will go down.

Am I being too naive, when I assume this?

Comment: no, this is not the case. The date is stored as DATETIME - not as a string in a specific format. The string you specify will be converted to a DATETIME, and those will be compared.

Comment: @marc_s: Yes, I agree. But, wouldn't the conversion take place for each row, when comparison takes place? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I hope not! I would believe SQL Server's query optimizer would be smart enough to convert those two boundary values ONCE and then reuse them for each row.

Answer (score 0):

How many columns does bam_Prestatie_AllInstances and the other tables have? It looks like you are oulling all columns and that can definitely be a performance issue.

Have you tried to select **specific columns** from specific tables such as:

```
select top 100 p.column1, p.column2, p.column3
```

**Instead** of querying all columns as you are currently doing:

```
select top 100 *
```